# Enable Scrolling on my sidenav

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, scroll

I am trying to enable scrolling on my sidenav in the same way that i usually do when i get overflow in normal divs, but there is something about the nav itself that is preventing me from being able to do this, such that the items on the sidenav-list that overflow the screen cannot be accessed.

here is the sidenav code in the html:

```
<div pageslide ps-open="ctrl.checked" class="blue-grey darken-1 white-text">
                <a ng-click="ctrl.toggle()" class="button">&#x2716;</a>
                <div style="padding:20px" id="demo-right">
                    <table class="bordered responsive-table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-field="id">Company</th>
                            <th data-field="name">Shares Owned</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                       <tbody>
                           <tr ng-repeat="stock in ctrl.myPortfolio.stocksInPortfolio">
                                  <td>{{stock.stock.name}}</td>
                                  <td>{{stock.qty}}</td>
                          </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
                  Portfolio: {{ctrl.total | currency}}
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here is what I was trying to do in the css:

```
#sentimentDataTwo {
   overflow: hidden;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
#demo-right {
   overflow: hidden;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I included #sentimentData which is a working css mod creating a scrollable div, but #demo-right is where i try to apply it to my sidenav.  Also the sidenav is a pop-out.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because your div doesn't have a height, which means the height is adjusted to your content. Let me know if it helps. If not, could you provide a JSFiddle? Even though you have some dynamic data, it would help a lot if you could prepare a similiar situation.

```
#demo-right {
   overflow: hidden;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea- it was an override issue due to a bower component, and modifying the original file was the only way we could fix it.